# PG Array not being saved to DDBB (Unpermitted parameter) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm having real trouble with this.

I have a product table with an array attribute:

```
t.text "color_attributes", default: [], array: true
```

I have declared it in my strong params as an array:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(
    :name, :price, :cost_price, :costprice,
    :active, :image, :provider, :product_family_id, :description,
    :shopify_image_urls, product_family_ids: [],
    customization_ids: [], color_attributes: []
  )
end
```

Then, in my form:

```
<%= form.text_field :color_attributes, placeholder: "333333,ffffff" %>
```

**I'm getting this error in my logs:**

Unpermitted parameter: :color_attributes

**My update action:**

```
  def update
    if @product.update(product_params)
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path, notice: "Actualizado con éxito.")

    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

I'm I missing something? I'm in Rails 7 and pg gem.

Thank you

Comment: The error has nothing to do with PG. The thing that you're missing is that `form.text_field :color_attributes` creates a single scalar value in the parameters but your params whitelist (`color_attributes: []`) permits an array. If you want to create array parameters you need to use `fields_for` to create something like `<input name="product[color_attributes][]" ...>` which is then parsed by Rack as an array.

Comment: In general using an array column like this is a bad idea as it violates 1NF. I would create a separate table and use an association together with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms